# Adding a Placeholder on a Form Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need to add a Placeholder on a form that I am writing. I tried the following, and some other variations without success:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:address, "Address:", placeholder: '100 Brooklyn Ave Unit 3' ) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:address) %>
    <%= label_tag(:citystatezip, "City and State OR ZIP:", placeholder: 'New York, NY') %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:citystatezip) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Enter Address") %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put placeholders in label tags, they should be placed in input fields, [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) in this case:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:address, "Address:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:address, nil, placeholder: '100 Brooklyn Ave Unit 3') %>
  <%= label_tag(:citystatezip, "City and State OR ZIP:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:citystatezip, nil, placeholder: 'New York, NY') %>
  <%= submit_tag("Enter Address") %>
<% end %>
```